# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, while sorting table column headers

Tags: c#, sorting, jquery-jtable

I get the following error in the browser `View` in jTable after the code has complied and ran:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I debugged the code and at this line of the code

```
newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
```

I get the mentioned error. I also confirmed it by commenting out this line of the code.

I am trying to do the `sorting` by hitting the table's column headers, but it's not doing it and gives the error out. Been on it for good few weeks trying to figure out but it just doesn't seem to work. Any help would be a great help and thanks in advance.

Here's the full code for your inspection:

```
public JsonResult TopPlayedInVenueList1(string StartDate = "", string EndDate = "", int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate-1k.xls";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
                con.Close();
                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(data);

                List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();

                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
                    {
                        TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("TrackID")),
                        Date = p.Field<DateTime>("DateTimes"),
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("TrackName"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("ArtistName"),
                        Times = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("Times"))
                    };

                    daa.Add(top);
                }

                var listOrder = daa.Where(i => i.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate) && i.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate)).ToList();

                if (jtStartIndex + 150 > listOrder.ToList().Count)
                {
                    int val = listOrder.ToList().Count - jtStartIndex;
                    jtPageSize = val;
                }

                var newlist = listOrder.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "Date ASC"; }

                SortDirection sortDirection = jtSorting.ToLower().Contains("desc") ? SortDirection.DESC : SortDirection.ASC;
                string sortExpression = sortDirection == SortDirection.DESC ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : 
                    jtSorting.ToLower().Contains(" asc") ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" asc", "") : jtSorting;

                if (sortDirection == SortDirection.ASC)
                {
                 newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                 newlist = newlist.OrderByDescending(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
                }

                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = newlist, TotalRecordCount = listOrder.ToList().Count });
            }
```

Edit: GetPropertyValue method:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj == null ? null : obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Comment: `item ` is not defined in your method.

Comment: @Murtaza - thanks but I'm not too sure on how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Alberto thanks for that and possibly seems to be the similar to mine. looking in to it now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `newList` contains elements and `sortExpression` has appropriate value.

Comment: thanks - I checked that while debugging the code. `newList` contains the data and so does `sortExpression`. Am I getting this error because I am getting data from a local excel file?

Comment: Than it's the `GetPropertyValue` method that throws exception.

Comment: thanks Andrew - I have updated my code above with the `GetPropertyValue` method for your inspection. You would know better if you could check and don't mind please.

Comment: `obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)` means you are trying to get property named with value of `sortExpression` in type `TopPlayed`. That one doesn't exist I believe. (You've used `...jtSorting.ToLower()..` and properties in you type are named with first letter being capital, right?)

Comment: thanks for looking into the `GetPropertyValue` method and you're absolutely right. However, you made a good point being `ToLower` so, I just renamed the properties to lowercase and still got the same error.

Comment: what's the result of this `obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)` code

Comment: thanks for that Andrew - `obj.GetType()` value is the first row of data from the `TopPlayed` list and value for `GetProperty(propertyName)` is `date` coming from `sortExpression` or `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "date ASC"; }`. hope this is what you had asked for :)

Comment: so `obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)` evaluates to `date` `PropertyInfo` which for sure is part of your `TopPlayed` type, and has a getter

Comment: yes Andrew, exactly! - going crazy over this past few weeks. Don't really know what really is causing the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51162/discussion-between-andrew-and-pv619)